# Angular 7 - Uncaught error: Network Error

Tags: angular

I am working on a Angular 7 based application and the app seems to work fine on Chrome. However, when I launch the same application on Edge, it throws the following error on the console.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Network Error Error: Network Error at _.sent (http://localhost:4200/main.js:19040:58) at Anonymous function 
(http://localhost:4200/main.js:19123:25) at step 
(http://localhost:4200/main.js:19061:13) at Anonymous function 
(http://localhost:4200/main.js:19042:46) at rejected 
(http://localhost:4200/main.js:19034:42) at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:6701:13) at onInvoke 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57267:17) at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:6701:13) at Zone.prototype.run 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:6453:17) at Anonymous function 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7187:17)
```

I am quite aware that the information provided here may not be sufficient. However, some pointers at what I should be looking into will help.

As I mentioned earlier - I get this issue only on Edge and not on Chrome.

I have pasted below the contents of the polyfills.ts

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
// import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 // (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

 /*
 * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 */
// (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

Thanks
Sushil

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, @Sushil get any solution?

Comment: Any idea to solve this issue ? I have same the issue,